# Retaining longest consecutive occurrence that does not equal a specific value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like so:

```
Value
0
1
3
-999
4
5
6
2
7
8
9
-999
3
2
-999
1
```

and I want to retain the most consecutive values in the dataframe that are NOT `-999`

which for this example would give me this:

```
Value
4
5
6
2
7
8
9
```

I have multiple dataframes (originally csv files) that have the `-999` values in different locations and I would like to apply the same method to all dataframes.

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far to try and solve the problem?

Comment: I have been playing around with this, `df=df.loc[: df[(df['Running'] == -999)].index[0], :]` which would remove everything after the first `-999`.  I actually would want to start by removing everything after the last `-999` first though, and then do it again, and then remove everything before the first `-999`,  for this example.  This method won't work on all my files though since there are a different amount of `-999`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with pandas Dataframes, but.. if your data is not in a buffer (have all values when you're executing the code). You could partition the list using -999 and then take the one with the longest length?

Comment: That sounds like what I want, I will look into how to do that, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `cumsum()` on the condition series which gives a unique groupId for each consecutive sequence from one `-999` to another. Then find the maximum length of the groupId and filter on that should give the desired output:

```
df['groupId'] = (df['Value'] == -999).cumsum()
df.Value[df.groupId == df.groupId.value_counts().idxmax()][1:]

# 4     4
# 5     5
# 6     6
# 7     2
# 8     7
# 9     8
# 10    9
# Name: Value, dtype: int64
```